# Python youtube-upload - Can't upload thumbnail even though my account is authorised

Tags: python, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload a video with a thumbnail using the python youtube-upload tool. The video uploads just fine but after uploading I get this message:

```
Using client secrets: D:\Programs\Python35\share/youtube_upload/client_secrets.json
Using credentials file: C:\Users\Name\.youtube-upload-credentials.json
Using category: Education (id=27)
Start upload: render\video\DCCA.mp4
Video URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*censored*
[RequestError] Server response: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.thumbnail",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "The authenticated user doesnt have permissions to upload and set custom video thumbnails.",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The authenticated user doesnt have permissions to upload and set custom video thumbnails."
 }
}
```

Now this is strange because my account is verified to upload custom thumbnails:

[Account Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lozNp.png)

I even tested manually uploading a video with the thumbnail but it works without any problems. I also updated youtube-upload to the latest version but it just won't work.

Does anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: please include your code.  Also ensure that you have authenticated with the correct channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your account is verified by clicking [this verify link](https://www.youtube.com/verify):

> "[Create custom video
>   thumbnail](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72431) If your
>   account is verified or you have live streaming access, you may have
>   the ability to upload custom thumbnails for your video uploads."

After that, try running your code again.

Answer (score 0):

OK I've realised the problem now and it was because when I did the account verification I was logged into a different google account .________.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and i found out that youtube require phone verification which enable you to add thumbnails.

So you can either go to : https://www.youtube.com/verify

Or

You can go to youtube studio ( to that channel where you want to upload video ) and open any video. Try to add thumbnail, if your phone is not verified it will take you ( redirect ) to the above link.

Do the phone verification and you are good to go.