# Service account doesn't have access to own channel videos in Youtube API

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, service-accounts

I created a service account credential in Google and tried to change the thumbnail of a video I own (it's uploaded in my verified channel). The account is, by the way, a managed account (indeed, it's a company email). The code below apparently logs in using the credentials in the JSON file downloaded from the Google API backend. `IMAGE_MIME` is `image/jpeg`, `CHUNK_SIZE_BYTES` is `1 * 1024 * 1024`.

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=" . CLIENT_ACCOUNT_FILE);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']);
$client->setDefer(true);

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
try {
  $set_request = $youtube->thumbnails->set($video_id);
  $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
    $client,
    $set_request,
    IMAGE_MIME,
    null,
    true,
    CHUNK_SIZE_BYTES
  );

  $media->setFileSize(filesize($image_path));

  $status = false;
  $handle = fopen($image_path, "rb");
  while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE_BYTES);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
  }
  fclose($handle);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "ERROR -> " . $e->getMessage();
}
$client->setDefer(false);
```

Sadly, it throws an exception. Running `getMessage()`, it pops out this JSON:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.thumbnail",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "The thumbnail cant be set for the specified video. The request might not be properly authorized.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "videoId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The thumbnail cant be set for the specified video. The request might not be properly authorized."
 }
}
```

I directly access the video ID, the channel is mine (and there's only one channel), it doesn't throw a login exception (it did until I made it work), and the image file exists. Has anyone had this issue before?

**Edit**

I decided to log into my personal account and follow the same process of verification, API activation, service account JSON download and script running. **The error is absolutely the same**, even when everything in there should be working now for a non-domain account, after [Jay's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452927/616225) answer.

I tried, *just because*, to use the company credentials with my personal video and try this. Same error. It's like I'm missing something on the whole process. I also checked the value of `getenv` and it's correct, and not setting it would pop a "Could not load the default credentials.", so in the end it's grabbing the proper credentials, although not *giving access to them* them somehow.

Comment: Is your account [verified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41956225/7663972)?

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase oh man, I hoped so much it was that. I verified both the account and the channel, waited for an hour already (in case a permission had to be refreshed, or anything), no chance. I even created a new project in Google APIs, enabled the Youtube Data API v3 and issued a new set of service account credentials. No luck. It couldn't be because the videos are on the Channel and not on the account itself, right?

Answer (score 1):

Service accounts are not members of managed G Suite domains (company accounts) and do not automatically have rights to any data that the service account creator user account has. See the note on [Google's domain wide delegation setup](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority):

`Note: Although you can use service accounts in applications that run from a G Suite domain, service accounts are not members of your G Suite account and aren’t subject to domain policies set by G Suite administrators. For example, a policy set in the G Suite admin console to restrict the ability of G Suite end users to share documents outside of the domain would not apply to service accounts.`

Options for you would be:

1. Actually perform domain wide delegation as described above and act as your G Suite user, not the service account.
2. Share edit access of the Youtube video with the service account email address.

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting though, that I used now my personal account, I verified it and tried to run the script to modify the thumbnail on one of the videos, and the video is still not running. I'll update the question accordingly.